# Outputting mysql data to aggregated HTML table using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, web-development-server

I have used a JOIN to select the data from a variety of tables as shown below.

[image: query output]

I am looking to output this to a HTML table using PHP in the way it's formatted below (1 of these tables needs to be created for each different `game_id`):

[image: desired HTML table]
I'm a bit lost because in all the `SQL/PHP/HTML` table examples I've looked up, I haven't found an example where it isn't just converting the output of an SQL query directly into a HTML table without manipulating it. e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_mysql_select.asp

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction as to the best way to achieve this? I'm not sure if I should try to write a better SQL query which better matches what I need or try to use PHP to do the heavy lifting.

Note: any team could have 1 or many players.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, as far as the SQL query goes, you're already done.

Molding the eventual html output to look like you desire, is from there on all up to the application (meaning PHP).

The first step is to crudely just recreate what you see on [image 1 - query output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43uRk.png) using PHP & HTML.
I imagine you've already managed (or can manage) to get to that point ?

The code for that would likely look something like:

```
$records = $db->query('SELECT .....');

echo "<table>";
foreach ($records as $record) {
    printf('<tr>
              <td>%s</td>
              <td>%s</td>
              <td>%s</td>
            </tr>',
        htmlentities($record['map_name']),
        htmlentities($record['first_name']),
        htmlentities($record['score'])
    ); // ( ...etc; only used 3 random columns here to illustrate)
}
echo "</table>";
```

Once you have that working, you can mold it to your liking.
First you'll want to group up the records **per game**, and within that also **per round/team**.
You can do that by replacing the code above with:

```
// Step 1 (Query the database for the raw data)
$records = $db->query('SELECT .....'); // same as before

// Step 2 (Organise the data in a way that suits your needs)
$games = []; // we'll order the data into this empty array
foreach ($records as $record) {
    $thisGameID = (int)    $record['game_id'];
    $thisTeam   = (string) $record['team'];
    // If thisGameID didnt already exist in $games, we add it (as an empty array)
    if (!isset($games[ $thisGameID ])) $games[ $thisGameID ] = [];
    // If thisTeam doesnt already exist within there, we add that aswell (as an empty array)
    if (!isset($games[ $thisGameID ][ $thisTeam ])) $games[ $thisGameID ][ $thisTeam ] = [];
    // Now we can add this record to that
    $games[ $thisGameID ][ $thisTeam ][] = $record;
}
```

Now you have a seperate recordset grouped per match per team. to create the output do something like

```
// Step 3 (Build html output based on the organized data)
foreach ($games as $thisGameID => $game) { // Iterate the buffer, per match
    echo "<table>";
    foreach ($game as $teamIndex => $records) { // And iterate within that, per team
        foreach ($records as $rowIndex => $record) {
            $teamHeader = ''; // Empty placeholder for a header field (the '<td rowspan=X>...</td>' field)
            if ($rowIndex === 0) { // If this is the first row for this match/team-combo
                $roundRowCount = count($records); // How many rows are there for this match/team-combo
                $teamWinColumn = $teamIndex . '_round_wins';
                $teamHeader = sprintf(
                    '<td rowspan="%d">%s round wins %s</td>',
                    $roundRowCount,
                    htmlentities($record['team']),
                    isset($record[ $teamWinColumn ])      // We have to account for the wins-column perhaps not existing;
                        ? (int) $record[ $teamWinColumn ] // like if the record has team='GREEN' and theres no `GREEN_round_wins` column
                        : 'UNKNOWN!'                      // <-- then we display this as fallback.
                );
            }
            printf('<tr>
                      %s
                      <td>%s</td>
                      <td>%s</td>
                      <td>%s</td>
                      <td>%s</td>
                    </tr>',
                $teamHeader,
                htmlentities( $record['first_name'] ),
                htmlentities( $record['score']      ),
                htmlentities( $record['Goals']      ),
                htmlentities( $record['Falls']      )
            );
        }
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

---

Personally, i would recommend improving the SQL query *a little* so you do not have the two team-named `..._round_wins` columns, instead:

- either: 1 single `rounds_won` column, containing the wins *for the team which the person in this record belongs to*
- or, alternatively: 2 columns `wins_us` and `wins_opponent`

Either of those changes are quite a bit more elegant and reliable (and you could do away with the $teamWinColumn fallback in PHP aswell then).

In order to recommend exactly how to do that, you'd have to show the `SELECT` query though and the `CREATE TABLE` statements for any tables that are used within that query.

---

Also, i'd left out the `<table>`-header in the code above for brevity. But if you want to add that in,
change:

```
foreach ($games as $thisGameID => $game) { // Iterate the buffer, per match
    echo "<table>";
    foreach ($game as $teamIndex => $records) { // And iterate within that, per team
        foreach ($records as $rowIndex => $record) {
```

to

```
foreach ($games as $thisGameID => $game) { // Iterate the buffer, per match
    $gameHeaderPrinted = false;
    echo "<table>";
    foreach ($game as $teamIndex => $records) { // And iterate within that, per team
        foreach ($records as $rowIndex => $record) {
            if (!$gameHeaderPrinted && ($gameHeaderPrinted = true)) {
                printf('<tr><th colspan="%s">GAME-%s (some_date_here): %s</th></tr>',
                    5, // <--- should match the total amount of columns the table has
                    htmlentities( $record['game_id']  ),
                    htmlentities( $record['map_name'] )
                );
            }
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this. To clarify on your point about the round win column, these columns actually belong to another table describing individual games rather than player stats - I used a JOIN to display it in this query so it's not as redundant as it may seem.

Comment: It isn't really about the redundancy, more about using data (namely the "BLUE" and "RED" team names) as column names. I'm not sure if its always exactly 2 teams or even exactly those 2 exact teamnames; but your `team_name` column is a VARCHAR/TEXT and can technically contain a million other values (including characters that aren't even allowed in column names even).

Comment: I totally see your point but here's the thing: there will always be just 2 teams and that's never going to change in this scenario. The name of the team isn't relevant either. The team name column is actually an ENUM but I could also have just used a boolean data type (and perhaps that would have made more sense).

Comment: Fair enough :) did you get the rest working ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem does not have a technical solution in Database, but I have the solution. What do you think about the first statement after it, and then the second statement and after it, and so on

An example of what I say

1. players: Oliver,Mathew,Jackson
2. scors : 100,850,400
3. goals : 2,7,5
4. falls : 3,4,6

If this does not satisfy the explanation, explain why

Comment: But I don't understand how you propose this would be achieved?

Comment: Simply, when an event occurs in the game, you update it in the Database. If you want help, tell me on Linkedin.